# Ionic 7.0.0, Angular 15.2.4. "ionic generate page auth" results in "TS2304: Cannot find name 'async'." error in file "auth.page.spec.ts" file

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Exactly what it says.  I'm running Ionic 7 and Angular 15.2.4.  I've generated a brand-new project using "ionic start."  I select Angular as my framework, and the Ionic project type is "blank."  The project generates fine.

In the terminal in my IDE, in this brand-new project with absolutely nothing else added to it, I type `ionic generate page auth` and press Return.  The page **seems** to generate fine, but then my IDE gives me a `TS2304: Cannot find name 'async'.` error in the `auth.page.spec.ts` file.

(BTW: If I ignore this and continue to generate pages, it continues to give me this error in every new page I generate -- the {pagename}.page.spec.ts shows this error in every page.)

Here's a screenshot of my IDE. You can see the error on line 8:
[image: Screenshot of IDE showing error in file]

Is there maybe a bug in Ionic 7?  Is there something I need to update elsewhere?  The last time I ran anything in Ionic, I was told to update Ionic by typing `npm i -g @ionic/cli` which I did...  That was yesterday...  And now, today, this is happening...

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: I downgraded to Ionic 6.20.9 (first uninstalled Ionic entirely using ```npm uninstall -g @ionic.cli``` then re-installed using ```npm i -g @ionic/cli@6.20.9```.)  Generated a completely new ionic project using ```ionic start``` and the same parameters as before (Angular, blank).  ```ionic generate page auth``` gives me the exact same error in my auth.page.spec.ts file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got it to stop giving me the error message by adding `async` to the import line at the top of the `auth.page.spec.ts` file.

So that line now looks like this:

`import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';`

Apparently `async` is deprecated, replaced by `waitForAsync` but I'm not going to bother to learn how to use that.  As long as this thing compiles and runs now, I'm good.